# AIR HARMAN 33 - Cant's compile for iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I'm using FlashDevelop for a while now to build my projects using Adobe AIR. The last version of AIR is AIR 33.0.2.330 and belongs to Harman. I was able to compile for Android, but for iOS, I get a black screen. Running a debug interpreter gives me a
`[Fault] exception, information=VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.external::ExtensionContext could not be found.`

Am I missing a parameter or something? The error code is really not explicit...

Comment: This error is related to ANE integration, I cannot be more specific too. Could be some ANE you were using before, but now it is somewhat incompatible with extension architecture. Maybe.